# Smooth Div Scroll Jquery Plugin endless loop not working

Tags: jquery, scroll, smooth-scrolling

Im trying to copy this example:

http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/clickableLogoParade.html

from the plugin.

However, you can notice that when the scroll reaches the last logo "RADIO SHACK" it stops.

How can I make it a real ENDLESS circular loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I saw your post here and decided to take a look at the page in question. The reason why the scroller grinded to a halt when it came to the Radio Shack logo was that the scrollable area didn't contain enough logos "to go around". So when it reached the Radio Shack logo and tried to swap for the next logo in the never ending queue, there was no free (not visible) logo to switch to.

I fixed this by adding a couple of more logos to the scrollable area. If you try the [same demo page (Clickable logo parade)](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/clickableLogoParade.html) now it will work fine. Sorry about the faulty demo!

**Two important rules when you implements Smooth Div Scroll:**

1. The combined width of all the elements inside the scrollable area
   need to be bigger than the width of the scroller.
2. If you are using the autoscrolling option, apart from rule 1, you
   also need to make sure that there are enough elements so the
   scroller can swap.

For rule number 2 you can imagine a man standing by a conveyor belt full of printed photos. Every time a photo falls off the edge at the end, this man picks it up, runs to the beginning of the conveyor belt and puts it there. And this goes on in a never-ending loop.

Comment: Hi,

I am getting this error when used the code

`TypeError: n.data("scrollableArea").children(":first").detach is not a function`

Also I posted a Question regarding the same
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134869/jquery-smoothdivscroll-error-slider-stops-on-last-image)